# How to create a thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

The method below is what I want to be done in that thread:

```
public void Startup(int port,string path)
{
    Run(path);
    CRCCheck2();
    CRCCheck1();
    InitializeCodeCave((ushort)port);
}
```

I tried what I could find googling,but nothing worked

```
public void Test(int port,string path)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(Startup(port,path));
}

public void TestA(int port,string path)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(Startup);
    t.Start (port,path);
}
```

Both don't compile,how to do that?

Comment: doesn't work, or doesn't compile?

Comment: You should specify the language used so that I (we) don't have to guess. Also saying, what doesn't work would be great.

Comment: Check the question tags - C#

It doesn't compile.

Comment: The language is spec'd in the tag.  :)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The following ways work.

```
// The old way of using ParameterizedThreadStart. This requires a
// method which takes ONE object as the parameter so you need to
// encapsulate the parameters inside one object.
Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(StartupA));
t.Start(new MyThreadParams(path, port));

// You can also use an anonymous delegate to do this.
Thread t2 = new Thread(delegate()
{
    StartupB(port, path);
});
t2.Start();

// Or lambda expressions if you are using C# 3.0
Thread t3 = new Thread(() => StartupB(port, path));
t3.Start();
```

The Startup methods have following signature for these examples.

```
public void StartupA(object parameters);

public void StartupB(int port, string path);
```

Comment: I get the error when using the "old way",but the lamba expression works perfect. :)

Comment: Clarified the required Startup method signatures.

Comment: Nice - I just posted an answer below using the "old" way, but didn't realise you could use lambda expressions to create a cleaner thread entry point.

Comment: @John: I _strongly_ encourage you to understand _why_ things work and don't work.  I get the impression you're copy/pasting, here, and that's doing a major disservice to yourself and your customers.

Comment: @Mikko: even your "old way" is using C# 3.0 feature of initializing ThreadParams properties :-).

Comment: @Milan: Good point. I did acknowledge this myself but probably should have mentioned it in the answer too. >.>

Comment: Edited now to use a normal constructor.

Answer (score 24):

**Update**
The currently suggested way to start a Task is simply using Task.Run()

```
Task.Run(() => foo());
```

Note that this method is described as the best way to start a task [see here](https://stephencleary.com/book/)

**Previous answer**

I like the Task Factory from System.Threading.Tasks. You can do something like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    // Whatever code you want in your thread
});
```

Note that the task factory gives you additional convenience options like *ContinueWith*:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {}).ContinueWith((result) => 
{
    // Whatever code should be executed after the newly started thread.
});
```

Also note that a task is a slightly different concept than threads. They nicely fit with the async/await keywords, see [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Answer (score 10):

The method that you want to run must be a [`ThreadStart` Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx).  Please consult the [`Thread` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) on MSDN.  Note that you can sort of create your two-parameter start with a closure.  Something like:

```
var t = new Thread(() => Startup(port, path));
```

Note that you may want to revisit your method accessibility.  If I saw a class starting a thread on its own public method in this manner, I'd be a little surprised.

Comment: I tried this,it doesn't work. ThreadStart t = new ThreadStart(Startup); << No overload for 'Startup' matches delegate 'System.Threading.ThreadStart

Comment: Startup takes two parameters.  If you check the docs I linked, ThreadStart takes no parameters.  We can cheat with a closure to make it look like two (in 3.5) , or we can use ParameterizedThreadStart and bundle the two parameters up into an object (pre 3.5).

Answer (score 5):

Your example fails because Thread methods take either one or zero arguments. To create a thread without passing arguments, your code looks like this:

```
void Start()
{
    // do stuff
}

void Test()
{
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(Start)).Start();
}
```

If you want to pass data to the thread, you need to encapsulate your data into a single object, whether that is a custom class of your own design, or a dictionary object or something else. You then need to use the *ParameterizedThreadStart* delegate, like so:

```
void Start(object data)
{
    MyClass myData = (MyClass)myData;
    // do stuff
}

void Test(MyClass data)
{
    new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Start)).Start(data);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class ThreadParameter
        {
            public int Port { get; set; }
            public string Path { get; set; }
        }


Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Startup));
t.Start(new ThreadParameter() { Port = port, Path = path});
```

Create an object with the port and path objects and pass it to the Startup method.

Comment: Just when I write your first line,I get "No overload for 'Startup' matches delegate 'System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart"

Comment: The startup needs to be "void Startup(object parameters)". You cannot use "void Startup(ThreadParameter parameters)" as you cannot pass an object to that one. You can cast the object parameters to ThreadParameter inside the Startup.

Comment: you have to change the signiture of the Startup method to accept the ThreadParameter class.....(the class you created with the 2 parameters).

Comment: you actually have to make the signature of Startup to take in an object and when you get in the method cast it to the ThreadParameter object.